# Re-render razor partial view returned from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following javascript:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (res) {
                    commentsField.append(res);
                }
            });
```

this ajax call is receiving a partial view from the controller successfully. The problem is that there is razor syntax in the received partial view which renders correctly on page refresh. Is there a way to re-render only this new chunk of cshtml code without refreshing the whole page?

#### UPDATE:

This is my view, it is a DisplayTemplate for a comment model:

```
@model CommentModel

<div class="comment">
@Model.Body &#8212; <span class="buttonlink">@Model.AuthorUsername</span>; @Model.PostDate.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("bg-BG"))
    @if (ViewBag.UserId != null && ViewBag.UserId.Equals(Model.AuthorId))
    {
        <a class="comment-delete-btn" href="javascript:{}" data-parentid="@Model.ParentId" data-id="@Model.Id"><span class="fa fa-times-circle pull-right"></span></a>
    }
</div>
```

And my issue is that the html inside the `if` statement is not showing right after retrieval - I have to refresh the page in order to render the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Can u share ur partial view code & rendered html  ?

Comment: I suspect your `ViewBag.UserId` is `null` because you make an `ajax` call and probably doesn't set the `ViewBag.UserId` value within the `POST` action. The `ViewBag.UserId` you set within the get doesn't affect your `post` action. That's probably why you only see it properly after refresh.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! Post this as an answer if you like so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `ViewBag.UserId` was not set in your PatialView. It's null then the If statement does not execute. that causes the problem.